# Sql server Pivot and create multiple records from one field and split other field

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

What my data looks like:

```
Name:   Animals(One-Column):
Bill    Dog, Cat, Horse
Bob     Dog, Giraffe, Snake , Horse
```

What I need to transform it to:

```
Name:   Animal:
Bill    Dog
Bill    Cat
Bill    Horse
Bob     Dog
Bob     Giraffe
Bob     Snake
Bob     Horse
```

I am unsure of the steps to take, there are anywhere from 0 - 100 values in the actual csv field.

**You will notice that the csv's are not consistent** (Horse is word 3 for Bill but word 4 for Bob), so I need a solution like:

```
1st Name  1st Word
1st Name  2nd Word
2nd Name  1st Word
2nd Name  2nd Word
2nd Name  3rd Word
...
```

Comment: This is nothing to do with `PIVOT`. You just need to `CROSS APPLY` on a split function.

Comment: If you have SQL Server 2016, there is a function STRING_SPLIT(), for older versions just google for string splitting functions, there are plenty available to download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create function [dbo].[udf_splitstring] (@tokens    varchar(max),
                                         @delimiter varchar(5))
returns @split table (
  token varchar(200) not null )
as
  begin
      declare @list xml

      select @list = cast('<a>'
                          + replace(@tokens, @delimiter, '</a><a>')
                          + '</a>' as xml)

      insert into @split
                  (token)
      select ltrim(t.value('.', 'varchar(200)')) as data
      from   @list.nodes('/a') as x(t)

      return
  end



  CREATE TABLE #TABLE1
    ([NAME] VARCHAR(4), [ANIMALS] VARCHAR(27))
;

INSERT INTO #TABLE1
    ([NAME], [ANIMALS])
VALUES
    ('BILL', 'DOG, CAT, HORSE'),
    ('BOB', 'DOG, GIRAFFE, SNAKE , HORSE')
;
SELECT * FROM #TABLE1

SELECT NAME ,TOKEN FROM #TABLE1 AA
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM UDF_SPLITSTRING(ANIMALS,','))A
```

output

```
name    token
Bill    Dog
Bill    Cat
Bill    Horse
Bob     Dog
Bob    Giraffe
Bob    Snake 
Bob    Horse
```

Comment: Msg 317, Level 16, State 1, Procedure UDF_SPLITSTRING, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 0]
Table-valued function 'NODES' cannot have a column alias.

Comment: Thank you.... so why did .nodes need to be lowercase? What does that have to do with column aliases?

Answer (score 0):

One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select name, animals, 1 as lev,
             left(animals, charindex(',', animals + ',')) as animal
      from t
      union all
      select name, animals, lev + 1,
             left(animals, charindex(',', animals + ',')) as animal
      from cte
      where animals <> ''
     )
select name, animal, lev
from cte;
```

You may have to set the max recursion option if you actually have 100 items in the list.